# Convert hex str to decimal value in delphi

Tags: delphi, hex, decimal, delphi-6, valueconverter

I've got a problem to convert a string representation of an hex value in integer value with Delphi.

for example:

> $FC75B6A9D025CB16 give me 802829546 when i use the function:

```
Abs(StrToInt64('$FC75B6A9D025CB16'))
```

but if i use the calc program from Windows, the result is: 18191647110290852630

So my question is: who's right? me, or the calc?

Does anybody already have this kind of problem?

Comment: By the way, it's pretty obvious that 802829546 cannot be right. The decimal representation of an integer cannot be of fewer digits than the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: what delphi version are you using? In Delphi XE I get 255096963418698986 using your code which is the expected result...

Comment: @Andreas starting with FC - it might be negative number, then it can be shorter :-)

Comment: You need to convert to UInt64, an unsigned value. See Arnaud's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808825/val-does-not-work-with-uint64

Comment: Since the OP considered both 802829546 and 18191647110290852630 as possible answers, I got the impression that we were talking about positive integers. After all, in most applications you know the sign of a value! Also, I guess that in most cases where you present hexadecimal numbers via the GUI, you are using unsigned values. But nevertheless, I made an assumption that wasn't entirely called for.

Comment: 802829546 is the result **when truncated to 32 bits**. Did you store the result in an Integer or a Cardinal prior to displaying it?

Comment: @ Rob Kennedy hi, the result is stored in a integer.

Comment: Simon, integer is 32 bit value (Like Rob Kennedy stated) so that is normal then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to use a Delphi library named "DFF Library" because I work on Delphi6 and the type `Uint64` does not exist in this version.
[Main page](http://www.delphiforfun.org/programs/Library/big_integers.htm)

Here's my code to transform a string of hexadecimal value to a string of decimal value:

You need to add `UBigIntsV3` to your uses in your unit.

```
function StrHexaToUInt64Str(const stringHexadecimal: String): string;
var
  unBigInteger:TInteger;
begin
  unBigInteger:=TInteger.Create;
  try
    // stringHexadecimal parameter is passed without the '$' symbol
    // ex: stringHexadecimal:='FFAA0256' and not '$FFAA0256'
    unBigInteger.AssignHex(stringHexadecimal);
    //the boolean value determine if we want to add the thousand separator or not.
    Result:=unBigInteger.converttoDecimalString(false);
  finally
    unBigInteger.free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 11):

In fact `802829546` is clearly wrong here.

Calc returns a 64bit unsigned value (`18191647110290852630d`).

Delphi Int64 type uses highest bit as sign:

```
Int := StrToInt64('$FC75B6A9D025CB16');
Showmessage(IntToStr(Int));
```

returns value `-255096963418698986` which is correct

If you need to work with values larger than 64bit signed, then check out [Arnaud's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11811666/800214).

Answer (score 8):

The number is too big to be represented as a signed 64-bit number.

```
FC75B6A9D025CB16h = 18191647110290852630d
```

The largest possible signed 64-bit value is

```
2^63 - 1 = 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 3):

to work with big numbers you need external library for delphi

[Large numbers in Pascal (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590171/large-numbers-in-pascal-delphi)