# Convert Str (hex int) to Dec Int

Tags: delphi

I have a hexadecimal string value. I want to convert it to an integer.

```
function HexStrToInt(const str: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := ??;
end;
```

such that `HexStrToInt('22')`, for example, returns `34`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert hex str to decimal value in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841972/convert-hex-str-to-decimal-value-in-delphi)

Comment: FWIW, I edited your question a little. You did say that you wanted a decimal integer returned. That's an oxymoron. An integer contains a value. Decimal or hexadecimal or binary or octal etc. refer to representations of the value. So, $22 and 34 are in fact the same value, but different representations of that value.

Comment: thank you, you are the best delphi master :)

Comment: @NadeemIqbal: No, it isn't. They're different questions.

Comment: @LeventTulun Quickest perhaps, best, not so much!!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 10,000+ answered questions shows at least how invaluable you are to stackoverflow, you have my respect :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest is to do this:

```
function HexStrToInt(const str: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrToInt('$' + str);
end;
```

Comment: Additionally, as may be useful, `function TryHexStrToInt(const str : string; out value:integer) : boolean;`  with `result := TryStrToInt('$' + str, value)`.  Useful for catching errors if the input is not guaranteed to be well formatted.  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt

Comment: I know this answer is old, but can you tell me how you were able to find out how this is implemented? When i look into the implementation (10.4) i come accross the line Val(S, Result, E); in System.SysUtils which links val to the System unit and there i am stuck to find the conversion.

Comment: @eggi I didn't learn this from the code, and the implementation is somewhat buried in the system unit as an intrinsic function. However, you don't need to look at the implementation since this behaviour is documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt

Comment: @Eggi but if you do want to look at the implementation, say out of curiosity, then just use the debugger to take you there. Enabled debug DCUs and step in to `StrToInt`. That will take you in to `_ValLong` in `System`.